# JSON Streaming is not being executed

Tags: arrays, node.js, json

I am working with big JOSN data and using JSON Stream npm module. I followed this [example](https://github.com/dominictarr/JSONStream/issues/109),

I have installed and using,

> const JSONStream = require('JSONStream');
>   const es = require('event-stream');

In the below code I am using some logic but not able to get the streamed complete JSON.

```
var options = {
    url: 'https://zzzzzz',
    verify: 'False',
    headers: {
        'Authorization': 'zzzz',
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'User-Agent': 'zzzzz'
    }
};

request(options, function(err, response, body) {
    console.log("JSON Data is" + body);  // here I am getting only a small chunk of json data

    var stream = JSONStream.parse('*');
    response.pipe(stream);              // body.pipe throws an error - body.pipe is not a function at Request._callback 
    stream.on('data', console.log.bind(console, 'an item')); // nothing is shown in console
    return body; // how can we return the streamed complete json data?
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I made some changes and it is working now,

```
request({url:'ssss',verify:'False',headers:{'Authorization':'Bearer zzzz','Accept':'application/json','User-Agent':'zzz'}})
  .pipe(JSONStream.parse('items..metadata.labels.app'))
  .pipe(es.mapSync(function (data) {
    console.log("Stringify "+ JSON.stringify(data));
    console.log("Parse and Stringify "+ JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data)));
  })) ;
```

Since I am using `recursive descent operator` I am getting multiple console.log messages.